# Session["User"] is lost sometimes in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

In my login page, User enters his username and password. If credentials are valid, then I "save" this user in Session variable.

On every page, In `Page_Load` event, I am checking his rights. If session of saved user is null, then application redirects him on the login page. In most cases user is not null, but sometimes the session is lost during use of application.

My login.aspx.cs:

```
protected void btn_logIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string username =  txt_user.Text;
      string pass= txt_pass.Text;
      if (checkUser(username ,pass)==true)
      {
          User loggedIn=new User();
          loggedIn=GetUser(username);
          Session["user"]=loggedIn;
          Response.Redirect("page.aspx",false);
      }
 }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      User loggedIn=(User)Session["user"];
      if (loggedIn=!null)
      {
           Response.Redirect("Index.aspx",false);
      }

 }
```

Every other .aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      User loggedIn=(User)Session["user"];
      if (loggedIn==null)
      {
           Response.Redirect("login.aspx",false);
      }
      else 
      {
           //Checking his rights...
      }
 }
```

Web.config

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"></sessionState>
```

**BTW** On localhost it works perfect. After i publish app, this happens.

**EDIT:** With further testing, I see strange results.
For example, when my user is returned to login page, becase "he is not" in session, he can get back to Entry page (see login.aspx.cs, why is that), after few times of pressing F5 (refresh page).

What causes this problem? Looks like session data is still here, but not always, or what?

Thank you.

Comment: what is in your webconfig sessionState?

Comment: See the edit...

Comment: Does this affect all, some, or just one user?

Comment: @MadMyche All..

Comment: Do you write anything to web.config, or the bin folder? That will cause a restart of the webapp, clearing all sessions (diagnostic: every session will be gone at the same time).

Comment: No, i do not. It works great on local host. Already checked IIS, nothing found.

Comment: Check the web (IIS)  log for time(s) in question, looking for dropped cookies or application restarts.

Comment: This comment has nothing to do with your problem, but you should look into Forms Authentication - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx

Comment: Can you please increase the 'Idle Time-out' value to the desired length in IIS? Try again...

Comment: See the newest edit, what i found out with latest testing.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have set

```
sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"
```

in the Web.config which means that Session will be useless after 20 miniutes.

This is a good method to enhance the safety of you web sites.

Comment: It's also useless after an application pool recycle. (`InProc`.)

Comment: Session is lost sometimes after 1 minute for example. This is not a problem.